# Calculating confidence score in NER

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, sequence-to-sequence

I am working on a problem on Named Entity Recognition. Given a text, my model is detecting the Named Entities and extracting that info for the end-user. Now the ask is end-user needs a confidence score along with the extracted entity. For example, the given text is: ***XYZ Bank India Limited is a good place to invest your money*** - Our model is detecting **XYZ Bank** as an Org, but **India** as a Location (which is wrong - the whole **XYZ Bank India Limited** is the name of the organization). Our model also gives a probability score for each token it classifies. But the end-user wants to know the confidence of the model that it did not mistake to detect the subsequent tokens as the parts of the organization name.

*Question is* - how can we efficiently measure that in a given sequence our model is detecting a certain sub-sequence as an Organization name (or a Location or something else) correctly or not? How can we say that it did not miss out on any subsequent or preceding token which actually a part of the named entity (like it missed *India Limited* in the above example)?

Comment: explain more what the confidence level should mean?  Are you asking what the confidence of probability for the word to entity?

Answer (score 1):

Named Entity Recognition is traditionally evaluated using [precision/recall and F1 score](https://towardsdatascience.com/entity-level-evaluation-for-ner-task-c21fb3a8edf) - the medium article gives a low down on how to achieve this
I recently happened to read this article on a new approach for the same. Please see the details in the attached [medium link](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-pathbreaking-evaluation-technique-for-named-entity-recognition-ner-93da4406930c)  but havent tried this out yet though

Comment: Thanks, Vivek. But my intention is not actually to derive an evaluation metric - but it is to communicate end user (who will use the model in production) that for that particular prediction task what is the confidence score.

Comment: Ok @SaikatBhattacharya - are you using spaCy NER or Stanford NER package ? I believe both of these provides confidence scores out of the box

Comment: Vivek, we are using sklearn-crfsuit alongwith Fasttext embedding

Comment: Sorry for the delay @SaikatBhattacharya  - i havent used CRF and preferred spaCy or LSTM for custom entity extraction. Please check the documentation of crfsuite - [https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sklearn_crfsuite/estimator.html#CRF.predict_marginals] in here there is a function which returns predicted proba which I believe can be used confidence score when communicating to end user